# Grid.Mvc + Entity Framework exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

Need help with Grid.Mvc. I'm passing `IQueryable` collection produced by Entity Framework and get exception

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        IQueryable<Document> documents = _dbContext.Document;

        var model = new DocumentListViewModel()
        {                Documents = documents
        };

        return View(model);
}
```

DocumentListViewModel:

```
public class DocumentListViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model CompanyName.DocFlow.Web2.Models.DocumentListViewModel
@using GridMvc.Html;

@Html.Grid(Model.Documents).Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add(x => x.CreatedDate).Titled("Дата");//.Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(x => x.IncomingNumber).Titled("Входящий номер");//.Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(x => x.Description).Titled("Краткое описание");
                }).WithPaging(10)
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

The documentation states:

> If your data source is database (for example) you need to pass IQueryable collection to the grid.  Grid.Mvc uses IQueryable interface to construct query expressions to your data collection.
>
> When you go to some page the grid invokes .Skip(N).Take(N) methods and when you sort data the grid invokes OrderBy or OrderByDescending methods etc.

Tutorial link: [Grid.Mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Paging&referringTitle=Quick%20start)

Comment: *When you go to some page the grid invokes .Skip(N).Take(N) methods and when you sort data the grid invokes OrderBy or OrderByDescending methods etc* what did you understand from this? it simply says you have to use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`

Comment: exception goes when grid rendering

Comment: Did you used `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` anywhere in your code ?

Comment: @Div thank you for your help. i added OrderBy in my action method: `_dbContext.Document.OrderBy(x=>x.Id);` and it works

Comment: Yes, that's it, you've already mention the solution in your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MVC Grid Description :**

> When you go to some page the grid invokes .Skip(N).Take(N) methods and
>   when you sort data the grid invokes OrderBy or OrderByDescending
>   methods etc.

You can do the sorting process encapsulate field get method  or you can do this same operation in ActionResult method

**Sample Code :**

```
public class DocumentListViewModel
{
    private IQueryable<Document> _Documents;
    public  IQueryable<Document> Documents 
   { 
     get 
     { 
        return _Documents.Ordery(x=>x.Id);
     } 
     set 
     { 
        _Documnets = value;
     } 
   }
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        IQueryable<Document> documents = _dbContext.Document.OrderBy(x=>x.Id);

        var model = new DocumentListViewModel()
        {             
            Documents = documents
        };

        return View(model);
}
```